# Passing variables between function in MATLAB GUI using handles

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to MATLAB so forgive me if this is rather basic question. I am trying to understand how to manipulate variables and pass the results between functions within the GUI.

If I set up the GUI using the GUIDE interface I get several functions. I would like to do a certain action when I click a pushbutton, save a variable, then use that variable in another function.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     handles.MyData = 7;
```

Now, since that data is stored in handles can I not simply use this in another function within the GUI in this fashion?

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     result = 5 + handles.MyData;
```

This is a really simple example, but I am trying to get down to the logic of how to pass variables. I know there is a lot of information out there and I have read it but I cannot get down to the logic of how the variables are stored in the structure and how they can be passed between functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update the handles struct, you have to store it using [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html?refresh=true):

```
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then you can use it in a different callback.

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly. If at the end of every function where handles was updated I add guidata(hObject, handles); it will update the handles structure globally?

Comment: @amkas90: Yes. Read the help (link provided in answer).

Comment: Thank you. I read it, but I did not understand what part I was missing. Appreciate your help.